# Formerly known as bodhi.zazen

Tags: discussion

Just a heads up here on meta ...

Time for a name change , just letting you all know, and yes it has been a long strange trip ....

Web site is still bodhizazen.com / blog.bodhizazen.com

Comment: I don't care if the question is closed it is more informational than anything else. The point I suppose is that I have been a longstanding member of the Ubuntu community and as such it seemed reasonable to give notice of the name change.

Comment: Thank you for the information ! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up. I'm sure we'll get used to seeing you in your new skin soon enough.

We work best as a community of real people. That means being familiar with the other users here. That's not a bad thing. It's not an exclusive "club" and not a pipeline to votes you wouldn't otherwise earn. Just being friendly and trying to help each other.

I'm slightly surprised by wie5Ooma's comment up there. Especially as they've been friendly with other people here on Meta before.

Comment: Nice words Oli, thank you ! :) "We work best as a community of **real people** ... Just being friendly and trying to help each other." I completely agree with you - would be interesting to know if other members agree as well ... I'm having a special person in mind. :D :D :D